# Objective C: Can a block variable be used only once?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Suppose I have a need for multiple block "calls", for instance a loop in which the block is passed to a another function in each iteration. Do I need to make a new block instance each time I call the function (like Example 1) or can I make one block instance that is called each time (like Example 2)?

```
//Example 1:
while(true){
    void (^block)(NSString* test)=^(NSString* test){
        //do something
    };
    [self callWithBlock: block];
}

//Example 2
void (^block)(NSString* test)=^(NSString* test){
    //do something
};
while(true){

    [self callWithBlock: block];
}
```

It compiles and runs fine the second way, but I suspect that any concurrency issues may not be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call blocks as often as you want. But you need to be careful about the context that is captured by the block.

If you have any values that are captured by your block, keep in mind, that unless when specifying them as `__block` variables, they will be copied.

So for example, this code:

```
int anInteger = 42;

void (^testBlock)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"Integer is: %i", anInteger);
};

anInteger = 84;

testBlock();
```

will print 42, not 84.

If you declare `anInteger` as `__block int anInteger = 42`, the storage will be shared and the code will print 84.

So, if you have code that is something like:

```
int foo = 42;

void (^block)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"%i", foo);
}
while (true) {
    block();
    foo++;
}
```

the behavior will be different from

```
int foo = 42;
while (true) {
    void (^block)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"%i", foo);
    }
    block();
    foo++;
}
```

This will also apply to pointers and NSObject variables, when you reassign the variable that holds the pointer or object.

To find out more, have a look at [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) from the Apple developer documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the __block variables. So if the blocks are called asynchronously, for instance by receiving data from a network, then I just need to make sure that they don't expect any local variable used in the block to be in a specific state?

Comment: Yes. If you use `__block` variables and mutate the captured state after passing the block to a function, which calls the block asynchronously, then you may run into race conditions. If you don't use `__block` variables, you still have to be careful when working with pointers and objects, because you can change the value at a memory address without changing the pointer to that address itself, so you may run into race conditions here as well.